# Possible network drivers for Windows PE PXE boot via WDS on Virtual Box

Tags: networking, virtualbox, drivers, wds

I need to run a WDS server on a VM using Virtual Box for my school, problem is Virtual Box is mandatory and it seems to face a lot of problems with PXE and especially Micrsoft technologies, I first needed to install some obscure extensions for PXE to work properly and now that my install environment boots, it provides an error saying it needs network drivers to access my network ressources...

Problem is i've been lurking google for 2 days already and I don't seem to find anything relevant, so I was wondering if any of you guys already knows the solution to such a problem.

I'd be glad of any hint you can provide :]

Comment: Do you want to PXE boot virtual machines or real one? How is your virtual machine's network connection confirgured? NAT, Bridged, etc?

Comment: Well it needs to be fully virtual, so I'm booting PXE virtual machines too. it's configured as virtual private network.

Comment: So you get the promt to boot from network and the client vm machine gets an IP and boots from the server vm? Just when you get to installing Windows you get an error message? I'd say you need to add the drivers to the boot .wim image.

Comment: yup that's my problem I know I need some drivers but I don't know where to find them, like WinPE drivers are usually hard to find so WinPE VM NIC drivers are even harder to find, I was wondering if anyone here already did that and knows the driver to pick...

Comment: Have you tried changing the virtual network adaptor?

Comment: No as I was too afraid of breaking what took me time to make work, I guess I'll clone my vm and try it up...

Comment: I set my machine to Intel PRO/1000 MT Desktop Adapter and found drivers for it here - http://www.intel.com/support/network/sb/cs-006120.htm. See if you can extract them and add them to yoru boot image.

Answer (score 0):

Change your adapter type to Intel PRO/1000 MT Desktop in Settings - Network - Advanced on the VM.